# Search REST API to filter Custom Managed Properties values

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using below mentioned query to get items from SharePoint lists(based on specific source results).

However, I would like to add filters to "Column1" in below query itself. So, that i can restrict few unwanted data in the query itself.

> https:///_api/search/query?sourceid=''&selectproperties='Title,Columnn1'

How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Append

```
&querytext='myManagedProperty:filterValue myManagedProperty2:filterValue2'
```

you can also add keywords

```
&querytext='keyword1 keyword2 myManagedProperty:filterValue myManagedProperty2:filterValue2'
```